# OpsCenter default native client connection and load distribution?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, opscenter

If we have 8 nodes in a OpsCenter cluster(Primary and Secondary) with 2 DCs. We have almost 30 nodes connected to this OpsCenter for monitoring through datastax agent. My question is all 30 nodes will make almost equal connection and load sharing(writing metric data to OpsCenter cluster) ? Or will make higher connection to Primary OpsCenter cluster and lower to standby? Any reference documents for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [storage_cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.5/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html#opscConnectionConfig__storage_cassandra-seed_hosts) section of the cluster_name.conf file, specifically seed_hosts, local_dc_pref, and used_hosts_per_remote_dc, control how the opscenterd connects to the storage cluster.  The documented behavior is correct as far as the opscenterd process itself is concerned.  However, the behavior of the agents is different.

Opscenterd passes the value of storage_cassandra seed_hosts to the agents of the relevant cluster and that is what each agent will use for initial contact points unless overridden by the [hosts](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html#agentAddressConfiguration__hosts) setting in the agent's local address.yaml.  The local_dc_pref and used_hosts_per_remote_dc settings are not passed to the agent and have no effect on the agent's behavior.

The agent uses the [defaultLoadBalancingPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.9/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/Policies.html#defaultLoadBalancingPolicy--) of the Java Driver, which is [DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.9/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html) with token awareness. The local DC is not explicitly passed to the driver so it will consider the local DC to be the DC of the first host it successfully connects to. This means each agent will either connect to one DC of the storage cluster or another.

TL;DR: An agent will connect **only** to local DC of the first live node the agent was able to contact. It is not possible to have a single agent connect to multiple DCs.  Which node the agent attempts to connect to is determined either by the storage_cassandra seed_hosts configured in cluster_name.conf, or if specified, the hosts configured in the agent's local address.yaml.  So if you want some agents to connect to one DC of the storage cluster and other agents to connect to the other DC of the storage, you will need to override the hosts in the agent's address.yaml and make sure the first hosts specified belong to the DC you want that agent to connect to.

Note that if a separate storage cluster is **not** used, the agent connects only to the local node that it is monitoring.

Comment: Thanks for the response, What I can see in my case most of the native connections are with One DC(DC1)and other have very low and write transaction are high on that DC1 where connections are high. Is this right behaviour of OpsCenter? sometimes nodes are hanging where the transaction are high so I am suspecting about this behaviour.

Comment: A single agent will always connect to one DC or another.  If you just specify your seed_hosts in the cluster_name.conf file and that gets propagated to the agents, then every agent will connect to the DC of the first node that it can successfully connect to (sounds like this is DC1 in your case). Like I explained in my answer, if you want some of your agents to connect to DC2 instead, you need to manually set the hosts in those agents' address.yaml to point to one or more nodes in DC2 before any nodes in DC1.

Comment: But if we put one seed host from DC1 and other seed host from DC2 then all my 30 nodes will connect equally on both DC1 and DC cluster of OpsCenter right?

Comment: No. Each agent will only connect to one DC or the other. It depends which DC the first seed host that agent connects to is in.  I've edited my original answer for clarity. Please reread it carefully.

Comment: Yes sure. Thanks @J.B. Langston